# IBM Portal 9 server on Virtuel machine(VM Image)

Tags: performance, virtual-machine, websphere-portal, websphere

Does anybody have experience installing IBM Portal 9 in a virtual machine(VM image) and have experienced very bad performance.

I personally do experience a very slow response every time the server renders the page.

The performance is much better and acceptable with  IBM Portal 8.

The Machine the VM image is running on does not have any resources issues when I monitor it.

Anybody have any clue what to optimize.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would verify the resources on the VM host where you are running the Portal VM.  I've seen situations where the Portal VM "seemed" like it wasn't using much resources, but the host was having trouble providing the needed resource to all the VMs it was hosting so I would start to notice slow downs on some of the VMs.  Try moving the Portal VM to another host or if you only have one host try powering down some of the other VMs temporarily to confirm if that is your case.

Comment: Since I am only an end-user I will forward you valuable input to the administrator.